# Can you solve the riddle

Tags: mathematics

Can you solve the mathematics puzzle?

[image]

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Puzzling.SE :D may you please provide a source of this puzzle?

Comment: The image is so cropped, how can we know whether the number on the left is 12 or 112?

Answer (score 5):

The 12 is a bit strange, so I just assume that it's the 2 that got cropped out (if its not then this answer doesn't work). I believe it is since the following image I found is similar:

[image]
http://funthingstodowhenbored.com/uploads/riddles/solve-math-puzzle-64-74-85-115-122/full-image.jpg

But assuming it is, we have:

> 74 = 64 + 6 + 4,
>  85 = 74 + 7 + 4,
>  98 = 85 + 8 + 5,
>  115 = 98 + 9 + 8,
>  122 = 115 + 1 + 1 + 5
>  (The next number is the previous plus its digit sums).

Comment: If you look at the way the image is cropped, it looks like there could be a digit before the 12, so it can't be a 2 that is cropped from 122.

Comment: @nikki That's what I thought too so I googled for similar images and found that one to make sure, if that's not the case I don't know.

Comment: It is likely a buggy app that just couldn't fit the number in the available space and lopped off the last digit. I think the puzzle image you found is near to being proof of that.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> 10
>  115 + 12 + 64 + 74 + 85 = 350
>  Adding another 10 gives us 360, the number of degrees in a circle